# Keep Meteor connection on Ionic hybrid app in background

Tags: cordova, meteor, ionic-framework, angular-meteor

Is there a way to keep meteor connection alive, also when the app is in background?
I am implementing a chat in my hybrid app, and I am using the "[WhatsApp clone](http://info.meteor.com/blog/whatsapp-with-meteor-angular-and-ionic)" tutorial.
However, when the app is in background, the connection dies and I can't check for new messages until the app comes back in foreground. So the chat is pretty unusable...
I tried to install the background plugin `cordova-plugin-background-mode 0.6.5 "BackgroundMode"` without success.

When the app is on background, I don't need very real-time sync, but it would be enough having the sync each something like 1 minute.

Thank you